# JAVA. Convert ListArray to List

Tags: arraylist

Why doesn't the code work?

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
//or
 List list = new ArrayList<String>();
//or
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
//or
List list = new ArrayList();
```

How i understand, list is interface. ArrayList implemented list. Why doesn't  type conversion work?

Comment: What's the problem? The first should work providing you've imported `List` and `ArrayList`.

Comment: Wow, so easy. Why didn't my IDE advised me to do it...

Comment: It depends on the IDE you're using. IntelliJ would definitely suggest the import.

Comment: I use INTELLIJ idea, she didn't advise me

Comment: You must have inspections turned off or something. When it was giving you the "undefined reference" error, there should have been a lightbulb that popped up. In that menu there should have been a suggestion to import those classes. If you didn't have that option, you may need enable it in settings; although I'm pretty sure that it's on by default.